# How to get all possible N number of combinations of 250 numbers in a list? (python)

Tags: python

So, say that I have a list of 250 distinct numbers.
For task 1, I want to get all pairwise combinations (e.g. 1 & 2, 1 & 3, 1 & 4, 1 & 5....). And then output these in a list such as [1 2 1 3 1 4....] **P.S. if i include 1 & 2, I would not want to include 2 & 1 (same thing in this case).

For task 2, I want to do the same as above but now all triple combinations (e.g. 1 & 2 & 3, 1 & 2 & 4, 1 & 2 & 5, etc.....)

Then for task 3, I want to do quadruple combinations, and so on.

Is there a way to do this so that the only thing I would have to change for the function is the # of numbers per combination (e.g pair, triple, quadruple, etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `itertools.combinations` can do that, but do you understand that it is a collection larger than the size of the universe?  At the 4 level, there are already 3 billion combinations.  The 5 level has almost a trillion.

Comment: The duplicate question is literally [the first result that comes up on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+get+all+possible+N+number+of+combinations+of+250+numbers+in+a+list%3F+(python)) when the title of your question is searched for.